# Why NodeJS KeepAlive does not seem to work as expected?

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

Quoted from [TCP keepalive HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html):

> In order to understand what TCP keepalive (which we will just call
>   keepalive) does, you need do nothing more than read the name: keep TCP
>   alive. This means that you will be able to check your connected socket
>   (also known as TCP sockets), and determine whether the connection is
>   still up and running or **if it has broken**.

So why is the following code **not throwing something** when the internet connection is broken?

```js
var tls = require('tls');

var socket = tls.connect(443, "google.com", function connected() {
  console.log('connected');
});

socket.setNoDelay(true);
socket.setKeepAlive(true, 0);
socket.setTimeout(0, function(){
  console.log('timeout');
});
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
socket.on('close', function() {
  console.error("close");
});
socket.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error("error", err);
});
```

Tested on MacOS/Debian, with NodeJS v0.10.17

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting [man 7 tcp](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6194#issuecomment-24009907):

> tcp_keepalive_time (integer; default: 7200; since Linux 2.2)
>
> The number of seconds a connection needs to be idle before TCP begins sending out keep-alive probes. Keep-alives are only sent when the SO_KEEPALIVE socket option is enabled. The default value is 7200 seconds (2 hours). An idle connection is terminated after approximately **an additional 11 minutes** (9 probes an interval of 75 seconds apart) when keep-alive is enabled.

So after ~10 minutes (on MacOS 10.8) node emitted an error:

```
error { [Error: read ETIMEDOUT] code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'read' }
```

Answer (score 3):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/net-keepalive

Here is a module which lets you configure TCP_KEEPINTVL and TCP_KEEPCNT per-socket basis.

> Provides high-level access to socket options like TCP_KEEPIDLE,
>   TCP_KEEPINTVL, TCP_KEEPCNT

```
var Net = require('net')
  , NetKeepAlive = require('net-keepalive')
;

// Create a TCP Server
var srv = Net.createServer(function(s){>
  console.log('Connected %j', s.address())
  // Doesn't matter what it does
  s.pipe(s)
});

// Start on some port
srv.listen(1337, function(){
  console.log('Listening on %j', srv.address())
});

// Connect to that server
var s = Net.createConnection({port:1337}, function(){
  console.log('Connected to %j', s.address())

  //IMPORTANT: KeepAlive must be enabled for this to work
  s.setKeepAlive(true, 1000)

  // Set TCP_KEEPINTVL for this specific socket
  NetKeepAlive.setKeepAliveInterval(s, 1000)

  // and TCP_KEEPCNT
  NetKeepAlive.setKeepAliveProbes(s, 1)
});
```